# Copy file from a computer not in domain to a computer in domain

Tags: c++, networking, authentication, copy, cross-domain

I have 2 computers in which one computer is in Domain and the other one is not in domain.
I want to copy a file from a computer not in domain to a computer in domain by providing login credentials.

I tried mapping network folder to a drive with WNetAddConnection2. Since we will run this exe as a windows service, handling of mapped drives is a big challenge.
Are there any other ways to do network copy of file?

Comment: What do this has to do with c++? By the way, if you wanna do copy of files, you could use scp or rsync.

Comment: I want to copy files through c++ application. Are there any c++ APIs to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't handle it with mapped drives. Just leave `lpLocalName` set to `NULL`.